# How to get the last record in an array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects `ObjectsArr= [Object1 , Object2,Object3, Object4]`
I want to show in my view the last object, how to do that in angularjs?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ObjectsArr[ObjectsArr.length - 1]` -- this will give you the last element in the array.
To display it in view: 
`{{ObjectsArr[ObjectsArr.length - 1]}}`

This will work even when the array has zero entries.

Comment: @sylwester's answer with `ng-if="$last"` below is WAY better.

Comment: What if the length is 0? `O - 1 = -1` oh dear.

Comment: @senthe  I strongly disagree. What if the array has a 1000 entries? What if they are going to have this value in a table of 50 rows? You're going to look over 50,000 entries for 50 results? Terrible performance. To fix Paul Rooney comment we'll have to use a ternary in the angular template

((condition) && (answer if true) || (answer if false))

Which would be 

{{((ObjectsArr.length > 0) && (ObjectsArr[ObjectsArr.length - 1]) || (0) }}

Blah. Looks like spaghetti code! If possible have your data return the result you want. Other wise consider writing a function to do this for you.

Comment: @MGot90 What are your assumptions about Angular's `$last` performance based on?

Comment: @Senthe It's not the $last that has bad performance, my guess is it performs the same as above. It's the ng-repeat that has bad performance. Why iterate over all items just to select the last value? Bad performance.

Comment: @PaulRooney @MGot90 accessing an element from array with index `-1` will not throw any errors. It will return undefined. `{{ObjectsArr[ObjectsArr.length - 1]}}` -- will work all the time even when the length is zero. Please give a try.

Comment: @Senthe   Please check the below plnkr links for the performance comparison plnkr.co/edit/5RxESflqbKlHAwafe125?p=preview and plnkr.co/edit/ItuNXqQYInWYYygmpQqD?p=preview

Comment: @VinayK Thank you for great answer!

Answer (score 19):

You can use ng-if directive and check if element is last by:

```
ng-if="$last"
```

please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.data = [1,2,3]
   

});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body >
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="$last">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works but the answer of Vinay works as well and he responded first. Thank you . I will up vote your answer

Comment: @Besa: you don't have to mark a response as 'best answer' just because it arrived first. You should instead mark whichever response helped you the most. In this case, that may be the same answer anyway. :-)

Comment: This is definitely the best answer here, not sure why another got accepted.

Comment: @Senthe Can you please explain me in what way this answer is WAY better?

Have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/5RxESflqbKlHAwafe125?p=preview  and https://plnkr.co/edit/ItuNXqQYInWYYygmpQqD?p=preview

Comment: Because since it's Angular native directive it's usable in other cases than the case from OP. Also much cleaner. And believe me or not but not only people who want to display last record come here from Google. After this answer I happily used $last directive in other case and I feel more educated than after your simple JS answer. It's a question about Angular after all. But it's only my opinion, no need to feel offended over it.

Comment: @Senthe we should not agree an answer just because its cleaner. We should consider the performance and best practices. only to render the last record in a list we should not be rendering the complete list. In this case ng-if directive will be compiled `n` number of times (`where n is the length of the list`)

Comment: I don't know ng-if=$last" implementation details. It is a directive for a reason so I think it's more clever than processing entire list only to get the last item, probably similar to your solution? Nothing here is actually "rendered", more like processed by Angular. AND it will still work after the current last item is deleted for example. (Also, if I was actually concerned about performance I'd never use Angular in the first place.)

Comment: I strongly disagree with this answer. What if the array has a 1000 entries? What if they are going to have this value in a table of 50 rows? You're going to look over 50,000 entries for 50 results? Terrible performance. To fix selected answer use a ternary in the angular template ((condition) && (answer if true) || (answer if false)) Which would be {{((ObjectsArr.length > 0) && (ObjectsArr[ObjectsArr.length - 1]) || (0) }} Blah. Looks like spaghetti code! If possible have your data return the result you want. Other wise consider writing a function to do this for you.

Answer (score 13):

For working with Arrays I recommend [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#last) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).
It will save you a lot of time in the future.

Both have last method:

```
_.last([1, 2, 3]); //Will return 3
```

See the links for API and installation.

As for viewing the result in the view, you can assign a scope variable in the relevant controller for the result and show it.

Controller:

```
$scope.lastItem = _.last(array);
```

View:

```
{{lastItem}}
```

Comment: Underscorejs is a verty nice library, but the OP requested an answer for plain javascript.

Comment: He asked how to do that in angularjs, Ofcourse he doesn't have to use those libraries but I think this tip might help him a lot for future arrays manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

New way in ES6 `ObjectsArr.at(-1)`

Check usage and compatibility on [MDN/Array/at](https://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

Answer (score -1):

you can use reverse!

```
count = [0,1,2,3]

count.reverse() 
//[3,2,1,0]

count[0];   
// 3
```

Comment: Reversing a list to get the last element is an unnecessary O(log n) operation.  If you just get the last element that's a constant time operation.